# SEF URLs in Drupal 7.7?

Tags: uri

I've enabled Clean URLs which has tidied my URLs up a bit, however I need them completely rewritten for SEO purposes. For instance my 'blog' content type should be '/blog/blog-entry/' rather than 'node/etc'.

I've looked around but I can't find a stable solution for 7.7 ?
Either a module or hook function in my theme would be fine

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go get pathauto http://drupal.org/project/pathauto
With pathauto you can set up automatic path aliases to do exactly what you want. It will basically allow you to set up patterns for how to build token based paths for new pages at the time of their creation. It's one of the most widely used Drupal modules and is an absolute necessity for any site.

Also, once it's enabled and you've set up your paths the way you want them you can regenerate existing aliases in bulk at the content overview page.

Comment: Thanks, am using it and it works perfectly - I'd seen that module before, however didn't install it as it says it's in development for 7.x still :).